# delete and add registry key .bat

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, command, registry

I export the key I want to merge .reg file.

```
        Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

        [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\bkkar\General]
        "Coords"=dword:00000002
        "StandardsViolation"=dword:00000001
        "WSCURRENT"="Drafting & Annotation"
        "QnewTemplate"="E:\\STD\\TMP\\BK.dwt"
    "ToolPalettePath"=hex(2):45,00,3a,00,5c,00,53,00,54,00,44,00,5c,00,54,00,50,00,\
      00,00
"TemplatePath"=hex(2):45,00,3a,00,5c,00,53,00,54,00,44,00,5c,00,54,00,4d,00,50,\
  00,00,00
```

I want to merge .reg file by creating the batch file .bat

Answer (score 0):

```
reg add  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\bkkar\General /v Coords /d 1 /t REG_DWORD

reg add  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\bkkar\General /v StandardsViolation /d 1 /t REG_DWORD

reg add  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\bkkar\General /v WSCURRENT /d "Drafting & Annotation"

reg add  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1\ACAD-D001:409\Profiles\bkkar\General /v QnewTemplate /d "E:\\STD\\TMP\\BK.dwt"
```

try this.

[REG command](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to merge .reg file by creating a batch file .bat

A much simpler way that the other answer is to use [`regedit`](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) to import the `.reg` file.

Example batch file:

```
@echo off
regedit myfile.reg
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [regedit](http://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) - Import, export or delete registry settings from a text (.REG) file.